# Retrieve sub-string after a certain character

Tags: java, kotlin

I need to get the text after the `-` character in a string.

For example,
I have a text, say "Name-John Doe".
I want to get the text "John Doe".

What is the best way I can do this?

Comment: First you need to write some code

Comment: i have updated the question @Reimeus

Comment: `replace(".*-", "")` doesn't work because `replace()` is a simple text substitution. To use regex, you need to call `replaceAll()` or `replaceFirst()`, which works fine, e.g. `"blah blah - stack overflow".replaceFirst(".*-", "")` returns `" stack overflow"` (notice the leading space).

Comment: @Andreas before i asked the question i made research and found replaceAll,but i dont know if its on kotlin, i couldnt use it i dont know why. that why i asked this question.

Comment: String[] strings = s.split("-"); Then ignore the first element, and split on spaces to get the words for strings[1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, you can use the `String.indexOf(Char)` method to find the index for the delimiter then use it to in the `String.substring(Int)` method to get the required substring. Like so:

```
String getRequiredText(String text) {
    int delimiterIndex = text.indexOf('-');
    return text.substring(delimiterIndex + 1);
}
```

In Kotlin, you can use the `String.substringAfter(Char)` extension function. Like so:

```kotlin
fun getRequiredText(text: String) = text.substringAfter('-')
```

or

```kotlin
fun String.getRequiredText() = substringAfter('-')
```

Comment: thanks mate, just what i wanted